# Difference between vapor-phase transport and vapor-phase deposition?

Tags: surface-chemistry, semiconductors

I am currently studying the textbook *Physics of Photonics Devices, Second Edition*, by Shun Lien Chuang. In a section discussing **The Invention of Semiconductor Lasers**, the author says the following:

> At the Solid State Device Research Conference in July 1962, an MIT Lincoln Laboratory group and RCA Laboratories reported extremely high efficiency (85% to 100%) electroluminescence from GaAs diffused junction diodes. Semiconductor lasers were invented during September to October 1962 by four groups within 30 days [9-12] (see the review article by Dupuis in Ref. 13). They were led by Robert N. Hall of General Electric Research Development Center, Schenectady, New York; Nick Holonyak Jr. of General Electric, Syracuse, New York; Marshall I. Nathan of the IBM Research Laboratory, Yorktown Heights, New York; and Robert Rediker
>   of the MIT Lincoln Laboratory, Lexington, Massachusetts. Among the four groups, only Holonyak's laser diodes and light-emitting diodes (LEDs) were created from single-crystal GaAs$_{x}$P$_{1 - x}$ alloy material grown by vapor-phase transport and were the only devices emitting in the visible region.

I had already read about **vapor-phase deposition** in a textbook on MEMS (microelectromechanical systems), but I was not familiar with **vapor-phase transport**. Reading about these two methods, they sound very similar, and I'm unsure if they're just different names for the same thing, or whether there is some difference between them. I would greatly appreciate it if someone would please take the time to explain the difference between, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper of interest is [C.M. Wolfe](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1713949?class=pdf) et al., "Growth and Dislocation Structure of Single-Crystal Ga(As$_{1-x}$P$_{x}$)", Journal of Applied Physics 36(12) 3790 (1965).

The key paragraph is:

> The GaAsP of this investigation has been prepared
>   by a closed-tube method utilizing a quartz ampoule
>   which is cleaned and baked-out under vacuum near
>   the softening point of quartz. The halide is introduced
>   by subliming a metallic halide, such as PbCI2, PbI2,
>   NH4CI, NH4I, etc.,ro into the reaction vessel. Typically,
>   2.2 g of source GaAs and GaP, 4-8 mg of excess P,
>   40-160 mg of halide, and a dopant are placed in an
>   8-cm$^{3}$ ampoule as in Fig. 1. This vessel is then evacuated
>   to 10$^{-6}$ Torr, sealed, and placed in a single-zone furnace
>   at 950°C with a gradient of 5°-15° along the tube.
>   Commercially available GaAs is used with GaP grown
>   from high-purity elements by a method previously
>   described.

So, yes, it is a vapor deposition technique, but uses a thermal gradient to evaporate from one place and redeposit in another place, controlled by the temperature.